# Characters used in string?

Tags: javascript

I found many question about counting characters used in a string and solutions
but how can I get all character used in string? Im new to JavaScript, im do not know to output this

for example
`"English-Language" to "E,n,g,l,i,s,h,-,L,a,u,e"` or `"Javascript String" to "J,a,v,s,c,r,i,p,t, ,S,n,g"`

Thank you..

Comment: Its not clear to me what your goal is. You ask about counting characters but you show strings that appear to be shorted. When this shows the expected result you should explain the rule by which the output string shall be created (since it appears to be shortened). (Use the **Edit** function below your post.)

Comment: @try-catch-finally Agree it is not explicitly clear and should be better explained. With a little deduction you can see it is all the unique case sensitive characters

Comment: `var str = "Javascript String";`
`str = Array.from(new Set(str.split(''))).toString();`
`document.write(str);`

Comment: sorry for not clearing my goal. the results i wanted is to remove duplicated character in string.  Im new here, now the site already found similar solved question.. Thank you for your afford guys..

Answer (score 0):

Very simple with `Set`: (just cast it back to an array)

```js
console.log([...new Set("English-Language")]);
console.log([...new Set("Javascript String")]);
```

And if you want it as a single string, do this:

```js
console.log([...new Set("English-Language")].join(","));
console.log([...new Set("Javascript String")].join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function and the `Set` class to achieve this like so.

```js
new Set("Javascript String".split(''))
```

The `split('')` part splits the string using an empty string as the seperator, so it just returns an array of all the characters. If you make a set from that array, it'll remove the duplicates. You can even pass the string directly to the `Set` constructor. If you want it as an array, just use `Array.from`.

Comment: You don't even need to `split` it, since `String` can be interpreted as an iterator

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score -2):

you can simply use `str.split("");`

```
const str = 'English-Language';
str.split("");
```

Let me know if you face any future issue.

or Second option is

```js
console.log([...new Set("English-Language")]);
```

Comment: This will not save as a unique set of characters

Comment: yes you are right, sorry this is only splitting string into array.

Comment: Posting images of console is not very productive or useful. Images of code should be avoided. There is one built into the Stack Snippets editor that will run right here in the page. Click on `<>` in editor